# 愛してる: 2 pitch accent patterns?

Tags: pitch-accent

I think I've heard both あいしてる{LHHLL}: ([1](https://youtu.be/Ff1SN8u1mgI?t=1914), [2](https://youtu.be/sHXg43rnqz0?t=387), [3](https://youtu.be/oRCsy25ER64?t=241)) and あいしてる{HLLLL}: ([4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoxvObLi9Q8&t=524s)(this seems to be the same person as 3 with a different pronunciation of the same word), [5](https://youtu.be/AQ0HBSt7Hyo?t=815), [6](https://youtu.be/MhC0rZiRAs4?t=195))

Are there any factors that determine which one is used? Or is it a case of free choice?

Answer (score 3):

aguijonazo makes lots of great points but I'd like to add in my thoughts.

I think the major thing that needs to be considered here is what is referred to as おそ下がり (lit. "late dropping") in the literature, but personally I like to think of as "accent blurring". My description of the phenomenon is that an accent can be stretched out across multiple morae, and the key for it to sound natural is that there is *both* a slide up and a slide down in the pitch, and they do not need to be accurately placed at all, in fact you can have the slide down be multiple morae late and it can still sound fine as long as there is a slide up.

Of course no one thinks about sliding up and down when speaking, this is more of a physical phenomenon where you are trying to get high enough for an accent and it just mechanically takes you time to do it, and as a result the timing of going down becomes more relaxed. Often the sliding up happens due to some extra emphasis or tension.

When the listener hears something like this they will automatically hear it as the accent being in the "right spot" (aka the right place according to their own pronunciation of the word, as long as that spot falls within the blur radius).

1. In the first link, you can sort of hear something happening late but it's actually

   > あいしてる
   > ／￣＼＿＿ (blurred)

   and not

   > あいしてる
   > ＿￣＿＿＿ (which is how a true accent on い would sound)

   So to me it actually "sounds"(= gets interpreted) like あ＼いしてる just with the accent blurred. BTW this is a pretty tame instance as far as this phenomenon goes, sometimes you get things blurred much more than this.
2. In the second link, it seems like the same thing happening to me here,  again with the degree of blurring being pretty minimal, and in addition in this case あいしてる occurs after こよなく which itself has an accent, causing the あいしてる to be terraced and as a result most people would probably not even notice unless they were told to listen for it.
3. The third link sounds the most noticeable because the blur goes all the way to the て, but even in this case I interpret it as あ＼いしてる, aka it's within bounds of being able to move the accent all the way back to the あ. But IMO this degree of blurring is to the point that it is noticeable and might cause an audio director to ask for a retake if it was a professional recording of something serious, for example (not because it's wrong but just because they might want something better enunciated).
4. As aguijonazo says, this variation is due to intonation, and is occurring due to the と which can cause words before it to have a raise towards the end.

Overall, this sort of おそ下がり/blurring is a *psycholinguistic* phenomena and therefore is a killer for the learners because it's not 1:1 with the actual auditory pitch. But learning to interpret it properly is key to ensure your mental representation of the accents is actually correct as opposed to a representation which only interprets extremely well-enunciated pronunciations correctly.

Comment: Do you have any theories as to why Japanese natives who hear words spoken with おそ下がり still *perceive* them as if they were spoken mora-for-mora correctly? Is it because they initially already have familiarity with these words spoken pitch-for-pitch correctly, and then, when they later hear them spoken with おそ下がり, their brain provides them with the illusion they are spoken correctly because they are *expecting* the word or phrase to have a certain pitch? (Similar to optical illusions where our brains can "fill in" geometrical space with shapes that we know "ought to be there" but aren't?)

Comment: Another question:  does failing to speak with おそ下がり actually make you sound foreign? E.g. suppose a Japanese learner *didn't* speak with おそ下がり, and actually learned to speak mora-for-mora pitch correctly. Would this then counter-intuitively sound weird to natives? Similar to how saying "don choo wanna go?" makes you sound like an English native, even though the technically correct pronunciation is "don't you want to go?"

Comment: 1. Pretty much. Relatively clear LHL-type patterns are the norm, and, using those as a foundation, natives' brains develop a sense for an "accented mora" in a word (or something equivalent to that at least). Note: single mora. When an accent gets stretched over multiple mora, then, the accent is interpreted as falling on only one of those (whichever one matches the listener's expectations).

...

Comment: ...

Natives don't hear significant おそ下がり often enough for their brains to spot the pattern and solidify stretched accents as a "thing" (i.e. as an additional mental category under which heard pitch patterns can be filed — おそ下がり patterns are instead put into the best-fitting "single-mora accent" box, because those are all the boxes they've got).

**Source:** speculation.

Comment: 2. おそ下がり is not really something you can avoid; it occurs naturally due to tension in your voice, and/or inability to modulate pitch fast/precisely enough in real speech. Clear accents _are_ what everyone learns / picks up / aims for; no one _tries_ to implement おそ下がり.

**Source:** my own guess of what Darius would say, based on his message history on JP-learning Discord servers, as well as this very answer (take it again from "Of course no one thinks...").

Answer (score 2):

The standard pitch is あいしてる{HLLLL} in this binary notation. However, it doesn’t mean pitch is flat after the first fall. In fact, there is at least one more, supposedly smaller, fall, and this usually comes between い and し.

However, when the first fall is not obvious for whatever the reason, the second fall may be perceived as the accent of the word. One reason the first fall is not so obvious as it is expected to be could be that あい is sometimes pronounced short like a diphthong. Moreover, when し is devoiced as it tends to be before a voiceless consonant like /t/, the second fall may be perceived as occurring after し, rather than before. All this combined may result in a pitch contour that would be best binarized as あいしてる{HHHLL}.

I think that's what's happening in #2 and #3.

#1 sounds OK to me.

#4 sounds like あいしてる{HLLLH} but that’s due to intonation.